# Как удалить replykeyboardmarkup в telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

как удалить replykeyboardmarkup после нажатие?

Возьмём код из step_example.py

```
...
...
...
def process_sex_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        sex = message.text
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        if (sex == u'Male') or (sex == u'Female'):
            user.sex = sex
        else:
            raise Exception()
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Nice to meet you ' + user.name + '\n Age:' + str(user.age) + '\n Sex:' + user.sex)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```

Как после того как мы выбрали пол, удалить (не скрыть) кнопки до следующего вызова /start и вызвать основное меню при помощи функции?

Answer (score 3):

types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

[pyTelegramBotAPI/examples/detailed_example/detailed_example.py - 25 строка](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/detailed_example/detailed_example.py)